# How to overcome precision diff of data types in .NET 6 and classic .NET Framework

Tags: c#, types, .net-6.0, precision, .net-4.8

I have migrated from (classic) .NET 4.8 to .NET 6 (Core) lately. I am seeing differences in the precision of datatypes (float, double). It is really hard to change the behavior manually (by using `Math.Round()` or something else) as the project is significantly big. Is there any way I can overcome this issue?

Ex: a multiplication operation in .NET 4.8 is returning 3748.9 where as the same operation is returning 3748.899999999996 in .NET 6.

Here is the line of code

```
Math.Abs(quantity * Price).ToString(Culture.CurrentCulture);
```

where quantity and price are of type double

Comment: Are you sure it's actually different and not just a difference in display format? Have you looked at the binary values (`BitConverter.GetBytes()` for instance) to see if there's a true change in values?

Comment: In .NET 6, there have been improvements in the handling of floating-point operations, and the behavior might be more accurate, adhering more closely to the IEEE 754 standard. You can try somethig like Math.Round(double/float value, decimals you need to get);

Comment: If your code expected a floating-point number to be exactly *anything* (except perhaps integers within a reasonable range) then the problem is *your code*; that's not how floating point works, or has ever worked. I agree this is most likely a display change, not a value change, but fundamentally: it sounds like you should have been using `decimal`, which works more like humans expect (but which is slower and larger)

Comment: `a multiplication operation in .NET 4.8 is returning 3748.9` what multiplication? How did you inspect the result? Are you *sure* that the result wasn't a result of text formatting changes? The real change in .NET Core was in formatting, not multiplication

Comment: Project > Properties > Build tab, "Platform target" setting.  Change it from AnyCPU to x86, repeat for the Release build, now your code produces floating point results the way it did in 4.8.  Computing with 80-bit intermediate results as provided by the FPU instead of the consistent 64-bit results as provided by the SSE2 instruction set.  This is not a problem you should solve.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: When you display floating point numbers you should almost always use a *formatting string*, like "0.#", this will control how your numbers are presented to the user.

Comment: This just looks like a variation of the [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Relying on particular results in a floating point calculation, to this degree of accuracy, is just asking for trouble. Either it is a display issue, or the wrong datatype being used, that "just happened" to look like the "correct" value before (with emphasis on the quotes). The end result might be that you either accept the change, or you rewrite the code so that it is correct to begin with.

Comment: @Corey I am sure that it is not a display format.

Comment: @MarcGravell The point here is not about floating-point number to be exactly something not we are doing anything about it. The same set of arithmetic operations are outputting values with different precision(as I mentioned in the question) in NET 6 and NET Framework 4.8

Comment: Your `ToString()` call does not specify a format or a precision, so the problem is with you. Try using something like `.ToString("#.####", Culture.CurrentCulture)`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring for more info.

Comment: @PeterB The problem here is I don't want to specify any precision or format(because there are numerous instances which I need to change and it is really hard to do it manually) and neither did I in the NET Framework 4.8. I just want the above line of code to behave the same in NET6 as it did in NET Framework 4.8. And I am open to tweak the code a bit to achieve the same output.

Comment: If the default format has changed: it has changed; wanting otherwise doesn't change anything. I guess the first thing you should do is isolate whether you *are actually getting a different value*, vs whether this is a formatting problem: I suggest `var hex = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));` (note that this is not *efficient* - it is designed to be simply a *convenient* way to compare the underlying bytes of floating point values; don't use it in "real" code - just use it to check whether the values are identical or not, i.e. whether the two frameworks give the same hex)